# It seems that mongodb java driver does not populate the whole document tree when found documents that contains multiple level nested documents

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb 4.2.8 and java driver sync 4.0.4 for mongodb in a kotlin project with Intellij.

I have an issue retrieving documents that have multiple level nested documents.

For example, I have a collection of documents defined as so:

```
/*Employees collection:*/
{
    ...
    "name": "Franz",
    "created_by": {
        "name": "Maurice",
        "authentication": {
            "username":"mat",
            "role": {
                 "name": "Admin",
                 "privilege": 2
            }
        }
    }
},
{
...
}
```

I retrieve this document like this:

```
val emp = MongoClients.create("mongodb://HOST:27017")
                .getDatabase(DB)
                .getCollection("employees", Document::class.java)
                .find(BsonDocument("name", BsonString("Franz"))).first();
```

**The document is populated as espected but the "role" nested document is not**.
In fact, the key "role" does not even exist.

```
val role = p.getEmbedded(listOf("created_by", "authentication", "role"), Document())
```

**role** is empty document !!!, it falls back to the default value.
Event after setting a break point in Intellij, **emp** variable inspection doesn't show "role" nested document in the debug panel when I go deep to check the role document.

Is this a limitation of the java implementation or I might do something wrong ?

Please, someone has an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is this a limitation of the java implementation or I might do something wrong ?
```

I tried the following code with the Java SE 8, [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) 4.0.4 with the results:

```
Document doc = collection.find(new Document("name", "Franz")).first();
Document d1 = doc.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("created_by", "authentication"), Document.class);

Document d2 = (Document) d1.get("role");
System.out.println(d2.toJson());
Document d2a = d1.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("role"), Document.class);
System.out.println(d2a.toJson());
Document d3 = doc.getEmbedded(Arrays.asList("created_by", "authentication", "role"), Document.class);
System.out.println(d3.toJson());
```

The Output:

`d1` value is: `{ "username": "mat", "role": { "name": "Admin", "privilege": 2.0 } }`

The output from `d2`, `d2a`, and `d3` is the same - the value of `role` you are looking for :

```
{ "name": "Admin", "privilege": 2.0 }
```

Comment: And, MongoDB v4.2.3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My bad, after careful investigations, it appears that this is not an issue at all. A bug in code lead to a misinterpretation. Once fixed, it worked as expected... Sorry !!!